# Is there a way to tell ReSharper that a method never returns null if a specific flag is passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, resharper

There are some methods provided by the framework that can return null. ReSharper will usually notify you with a warning saying that this is a `Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'` if no null-check was made before.

An example would be `Type.GetType()`. This method just expects a string as parameter, which would be the type name and returns the corresponding `Type`. If the type cannot be found, null is returned. This is an example where ReSharper notifies about a possible NullReferenceException.

[image]

BUT this method has another overload which expects another boolean parameter called `throwOnNull`. If this is set true, the warning from ReSharper will disappear.

[image]

Is there a way to implement such mechanic in my own library? We have a library with some extension methods on `HttpContext`. Some of those extension methods can return null.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is hardcoded knowledge. But you can use `[NotNull]` and `[CanBeNull]` to tell resharper an intended behaviour. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Annotations_in_Source_Code.html) for more information. But I don't see a solution to add `[CanBeNull]` having any contraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `JetBrains.Annotations`'s `ContractAnnotation` attribute.

Using the example you provided. Given the following class:

```
public class MyType
{
    [ContractAnnotation("throwOnNull:true => notnull")]
    public static Type GetType(string name, bool throwOnNull)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ReSharper will mark the following as `Possible System.NullReferenceException`:

```
var type = MyType.GetType("Some.Type", false);
var typeName = type.FullName;
```

While this is OK:

```
var type = MyType.GetType("Some.Type", true);
var typeName = type.FullName;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was similarly able to use "null => true" on one of our methods that checks that a nullable type has a valid value (which includes not being null). This got rid of the "Possible InvalidOperationException" message when accessing its Value property after performing the check.